# Is there a PHP function converting accentuated letters in database into html code?

Tags: php

There is a `MySQL` database containing data with `accentuated` letters like `é`. I want to display it in my `PHP` page , but the problem is that there are unrecognized characters displayed because of the `accent`. So is there a `function` to convert accent to HTML code , for example `é` is converted to `&eacute;` !

Comment: [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)?

Comment: @DaveRandom should be an answer

Comment: Yes, but for that you'd have to get your *encoding problems* straightened out to begin with. If you did that, you wouldn't need to convert them to HTML entities. See [How to handle Unicode in a web app](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Comment: You should store in the database as utf8 (for the table encoding and the database encoding) and have a utf8 meta tag at the top of your page (that would solve part of it without having to convert stuff before saving it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using `htmlentities` you should use the unicode charset in your files, e.g.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"');
```

To be on the safe side, you can add the following meta tag to your html files:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Then, make sure that your data base connection uses utf8:

```
mysql_connect(...);
mysql_select_database(...);

mysql_set_charset('utf-8');
```

Then, all browsers should display the special characters correctly.

The advantage is that you can easily use unicode characters everywhere in your php files - for example the copyright sign (©) or a dash (–) - given that your php files are encoded in utf-8, too.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and/or [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can easily make one yourself with str_replace:

```
function txtFormat($input){

    $output = str_replace('/\à/','&#201;',$input);
    $output = str_replace('/\è/','&#232;',$output);
    $output = str_replace('/\é/','&#233;',$output);
    $output = str_replace('/\ì/','&#236;',$output);
    $output = str_replace('/\ò/','&#242;',$output);
    $output = str_replace('/\ù/','&#249;',$output);

    return $output;

}
```

Comment: But ... why? `htmlentities` does exactly the same, but faster.

Comment: sorry I didn't read your answer yet, it's actually preatty helpful to me too! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```

And don't encode your data via utf8_encode() function before inserting into database
hope this will solve your problem :)